# Error : 1506741262570 Marionette INFO Listening on port 2828 using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I want to open `Google` using `Selenium` using Firefox. The firefox version I am using is `52.3.0 (64-bit)`. I am trying in this way;

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C://geckodriver-v0.19.0-win64_2//geckodriver.exe");    // Setting GECKODRIVER
WebDriver WD = new FirefoxDriver();
WD.get("http://www.google.com");
```

But on running the program, it goes to sleep and the output comes as;

```
1506741259735   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.19.0
1506741259744   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:31605
1506741260475   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\SPERID~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.viiF05x2u2Ct"
1506741262570   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 2828
```

What's wrong here? I am unable to understand that why it is working as?

Comment: Any error? Is the browser opening and browsing the url?

Comment: @TarunLalwani . Yes Browser is opening but the url is not browsing.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to define the `Firefox` version you want to use.
Most of the issue I have faced trying `Selenium` is around version issues, with no clear messages or info on which versions are compatible.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "/path/to/another/firefox/dot/exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the latest **`Selenium-Java`** client v`3.6.0` and **`geckodriver`** v`0.19.0`, while mentioning the absolute path of the `geckodriver.exe` you need to use either the single forward slash **`(/)`** or the escaped back slash **`(\\)`** as follows:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Utility/BrowserDrivers/geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com");
    System.out.println("Application opened");
    System.out.println("Page Title is : "+driver.getTitle());
    driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the Firefox version.

I downloaded Firefox ESR (52.3.0) for use with Selenium IDE, but when I used WebDriver it was also automatically using the ESR version of Firefox and failing in the way you describe.

When I uninstalled Firefox ESR version, WebDriver automatically used Firefox 55.0.3 and it worked fine.

Edit: I decided I still wanted ESR, so I re-installed it and changed the default install path from "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox" to "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox ESR" therefore Selenium WebDriver couldn't find it easily and used the newer version of Firefox.

Comment: Another tip I have found is that you can set the location of geckodriver and other browser drivers in your environment variables. This means that you won't need the line: "System.setProperty..."

Instead, add C:/geckodriver-v0.19.0-win64_2/ to your Path variable and store all your browser drivers such as for Firefox, Chrome, Safari in that path.

Answer (score -2):

Try setting the Marionette capability to true,

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setCapability("marionette", true);
WebDriver WD = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Comment: As the logs already show `Marionette`, why would this be needed?